# Can glDrawArrays and glBufferSubData work in parallel?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Assume I have two threads: One is the render thread, the other one the upload thread. They share VBO data via context resource sharing. The upload thread copies data to a VBO the render thread uses via glBufferSubData.

Question: Will the glBufferSubData calls block drawcalls performed on a different range in the same VBO? Or can I render from a VBO that is currently uploaded to if I draw a range that the upload does not affect?

For clarification: I want to know whether while glBufferSubData writes to one range in the VBO a draw call reading a different part of the VBO can proceed.